# How to insert form data from multible fields into one sql table column

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, forms, sql-insert

Consider the following html fields.

```
<form style="width:100px" action="phpformposttest.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="Area">
<input type="text" name="Area2">
<input type="text" name="Zip">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Using php, how do i insert ("Area", "Area2", and "Zip") into one column collected from these multiple inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert **JSON** data.

```
$arr=array("Area"=>$_POST['Area'],"Area2"=>$_POST['Area2'],"Zip"=>$_POST['Zip']);
$json=json_encode($arr);
```

And insert **$json** value to database. In **PDO** :

```
$sql=$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES(?)");
$sql->execute(array($json));
```

You can retrieve back **Area**, **Area2** & **Zip** with **json_decode** :

```
$arr=json_decode($json,true);
echo $arr['Area'];
echo $arr['Area2'];
echo $arr['Zip'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a single string:

```
  $area1 = $_POST['Area1'];
        $area2 = $_POST['Area2'];
        $zip = $_POST['Zip'];
        //prepare single string
        $address = 'Area1: '.$area1.' Area2: '.$area2.' Zip:'.$zip;
        //Now insert it into a single column of table
```

Answer (score 0):

Use implode And explode Function of PHP :-

```
$arr = array($_POST['Area'], $_POST['Area2'], $_POST['Zip']);
$temp=implode(",",$arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not store as separate columns.. It's always easier to leave data apart then to have to parse it. Also having them all together will make it harder to query.