# How to insert data from 3 different input fields together in one column of table in mysql database in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to insert data from different input fields like country, state and city in single column location in my database table. I have fields like this now.

```
+----------------+----------------+----------+
|    zipcode     |      city      |   state  |
+----------------+----------------+----------+
|     10954      |     Nanuet     |    NY    |
+----------------+----------------+----------+
```

But, I want  to insert data like this.

```
+---------------------+
|      location       |
+---------------------+
| 10954 - Nanuet, NY  |
+---------------------+
```

How to do it in codeigniter?

Comment: You must have tried something for this!!

Comment: Is there any issue / error / warning you get while **concatenating** these input fields?

Comment: This question was asked and answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522692/how-to-insert-form-data-from-multible-fields-into-one-sql-table-column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ZIP  = $this->input->post('zipcode');
$CITY = $this->input->post('CITY');
$STATE = $this->input->post('STATE');
$location = $ZIP  .' - '.$CITY .' , '.$STATE ;
```

you can insert that location variable now, your model query;

```
$this->db->insert('tablename', array('location=>$locaiton'))
```

Comment: your welcome :) if you ever got any other query regarding codeigniter you can email me infowiz.tariq@gmail.com

Comment: yeh sure sir i will, thanx once again